# Applying memory limits to screen sessions

Tags: linux, memory, gnu-screen, exploit

You can set memory usage limits for standard Linux applications in: `/etc/security/limits.conf`

Unfortunately, **I previously thought** <strike>these limits only apply to user applications and not system services</strike>. This means that users can by bypass their limits by launching applications through a system service such as `screen`. I'd like to know if it's possible to let users use `screen` but still enforce application limits.

Jeff had the great idea of using `nohup` which obeys user limits (wonderful!), but I would still like to know if it's possible to mimic the useful windowing features of `screen`.

**EDIT:**

It seems my `screen` sessions are now obeying my hard address space limits defined in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.  I must have been making some mistake.  I recently installed `cpulimit`, but I doubt that's the solution.Thanks for the `nohup` tip, Jeff! It's very useful.

[Link to CPU Limit package](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: If you give someone access to your system, the fact that they are able to spawn processes is not an exploit. I'd rephrase the title of your question.

Comment: The exploit comes from users being able to circumvent limits defined in `limits.conf` by using `screen`. I think the term "exploit" is appropriate.

Comment: Which limits are they able to circumvent, exactly?

Comment: Address space limits, CPU time, number of locks, and others as defined in `limits.conf`. Link here: http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to comment on whether that's an actual 'exploit' or intended behavior, but the work-around for this situation is to not allow access to `screen`. If they/you need to run a process while they're logged out they could use `nohup`.